# TypeSafe Activator 1.3.2 - Corporate proxy

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I am trying to create the sample Play Framework projects through the typesafe activator ui.
According to `https://typesafe.com/activator/docs` I have done the following:

Created `c:\users\myuser\.activator\activatorconfig.txt` with:

```
# Proxy settings
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyname
-Dhttp.proxyPort=80
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyname
-Dhttps.proxyPort=80
# Here we configure the hosts which should not go through the proxy.  You should include your private network, if applicable.
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1"
# These are commented out, but if you need to use authentication for your proxy, please fill these out.
#-Dhttp.proxyUser=PUT YOUR PROXY USER HERE
#-Dhttp.proxyPassword=PUT YOUR PROXY PASSWORD HERE
```

And also created `c:\users\myuser\.sbt\jvmargs` which contains the exact same properties as `activatorconfig.txt`. `jvmargs` is just a text file with no extension.

When I run `activator ui` and then try to create some sample application I get the following in the console:

```
Checking for a newer version of Activator (current version 1.3.2)...
   ... failed to get latest version information: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
Found previous process id: 12236
Local repository: activator-launcher-local @ file:////C:/activator-1.3.2/repository
Local repository: activator-local @ file:////C:/activator-1.3.2/repository
Play server process ID is 7304
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:8888
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] c.a.h.AmazonHttpClient - Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: proxyname Proxy Port: 80
[info] application - Failed to record a clone of 'hello-slick-2.1': java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
[info] application - Failed to record a clone of 'hello-slick-2.1': java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

And in the UI obviously the process doesnt continue to create the sample. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: its -Dhttp and -Dhttps

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the proxy to your system variables (Control Panel -> System -> Edit the system environment variables -> Environment variables):

`HTTP_PROXY=http://<host>:<port>`

After setting the variable you need to reboot your computer.

Result should look like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3dqHRwrCMBCZUVIMElOeDV5UU0/view?usp=sharing